# SQL query is in "Execution" status and it keeps on running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to run a simple query in `SQL 2102` `select count(*) from cab_details` , but it keeps on executing.

If i restart the sql service , the result is shown in just one second. (Count is around 250,000 - not a bigger value)

After 10 mins , if i try to execute the same query - again it keeps on executing.

I wanted to restart the `SQL service` every 10 mins to get the result.

Anyone have any clue

Comment: Is there any blocking for the query executing on a similar database?

Comment: This is strange, did you tried checking if something is blocking the query ? Dont restart SQl Server service what it is doing is it is killing all connections and flushing all plans and your query is getting free access. I am sure some command is trying to take exclusive lock on table and you query is blocked

Comment: check the activity monitor (rightclick on your sqlserver instance). It sounds like someone blocks you from reading some data.

Answer (score 1):

If a query keeps running it has to be waiting for something.

Since your query is fairly simple and runs fine after a restore it's most likely waiting on a lock.

Some other query is probably holding a lock on the table blocking your query, but that other query is killed when you restart SQL Server. That query most likely is run again a bit later locking the table again, which results in your query being blocked again after 10 minutes.

The problem isn't really with your query but with the query generating the lock so that is what you should be investigation.

There is plenty of information on the web on how to investigate blocking but one of the first steps could be using [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com) to find out the query that's causing the blocking and the application generating it.